# Regex to match a word with .D. in it, like Ph.D. or M.D. -

Tags: .net, regex

I am struggling to define a regular expression for matching a whole word that contains the substring `.D.` - such as found in Ph.D. or M.D., but also in other qualifications.  The .D. may not always fall at the end of the word.

My poor starting attempt is:

```
 [a-zA-Z\.]?\.D\.[a-zA-Z\.]?
```

But this fails completely to match either Ph.D. or M.D.

I'm using .NET regex but an example in another language that gives me a head start would be great.

Comment: Your question is vague. Please provide a list of "other qualifications" as well as exactly what you would like to match. As it stands even \.D\. would match, although I am positive this is not what you want to match.

Comment: Ok, if I have a string containing "Ian Kelly Ph.D." I would be able to like to match the characters "Ph.D." in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are confusing `?` and `*`.

> `[a-zA-Z\.]*\.D\.[a-zA-Z\.]*`

`*` is what you need to be using since it can allow for more than 1 match (on the character set in `[a-zA-Z\.]`) to be found.

`[a-zA-Z\.]?` will match 0 or 1 character only.

`[a-zA-Z\.]*` will match 0-* characters.

So the reason you weren't getting a match on your first regex was because you had more than 1 qualifying characters in your string.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should try this way

```
((?:[a-zA-Z]+\.D\.)|(?:D\.[a-zA-Z]+\.))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my suggestion:

```
[a-zA-Z\.]*\.D\.[a-zA-Z\.]*
```

I just changed the `?` to `*`.

Comment: Feeling dumb now, I thought ? was 0 or more.

Comment: @iandotkelly: you're not dumb, you just mixed it with `*`. `?` means zero ore one repetition.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
(\S+\.D\.\S*)
```

This might be a little loose, but it gives any non-whitespace followed by .D. followed by 0 or more whitespace, and captures the entire word for later use.  Just leave out the parens if you dont want to capture, but your question made it sound like you did.

Answer (score 2):

I would use this :

```
\b\w+\.D\.
```

This should match all preceding words adjacent to `.D.`

Comment: Thanks - i wanted to constrain it to alphabetic characters, but I appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: No prob. Just exchange \w with [a-z] and use case insensitive match.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely clear on your requirements, but this might work:
`[A-Za-z]*\.D\.[A-Za-z.]*`